# How to share context to ReactDOM.render from the element's parent component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, react-component, react-portal

Here's a link to the codebox of my problem.[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-context-into-contenteditable-xi2j9)

Currently, I have this [setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk0Tw.png). Add slot adds a card inside the ckeditor component.  You can create multiple slots. Increment/Decrement counter increments/decrements the counter outside ckeditor. However, I want the increments/decrements to reflect inside the slots as well. Unable to find the right way to do this, Portals don't work since there are rendered within the same DOM. ReactDOM.render doesn't have a way of passing context from the parent component of the element to the inserted component. Does anyone know a way to solve this?

Comment: Hi Nidhi! It seems you're using a standalone version of CKEditor, while there is an existing ckeditor-react integration available: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_react.html. If I have enough time, I can try to compose an example with your code, adjusted for the react port (or unless someone else does it before me). The ckeditor-react version significantly simplifies data bindings with the editor, you might find an example in the doc.

Comment: That would be great, I'll try too.

Comment: It didn't work and for the purposes of the problem I am trying to solve, is there a way to solve it without using the react version?